# What is the mechanism that allows failure::Error to represent all errors?

Tags: rust

For example:

```
extern crate failure;

use std::fs::File;

fn f() -> std::result::Result<(), failure::Error> 
    let _ = File::open("test")?;
    "123".parse::<u32>()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

What is the technique that allows `failure::Error` to be able to represent `std::io::Error`, the parse error, and any other custom error types? What is the minimal implementation to recreate this ability?

Answer (score 2):

There are two mechanisms at play here.

The first mechanism is the question mark operator, which [returns `Err(From::from(e))` when it encounters an `Err(e)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#the-question-mark-operator). If the function return type is `Result<T, E>`, this allows us to return any error type `F` that `E` implements `From<F>` for.

From the documentation of the `failure::Error` type, we can see that there is a [generic `From` implementation for all types implementing the `failure::Fail` trait](https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.5/failure/struct.Error.html#impl-From%3CF%3E), and there is a [generic implementation of `Fail` for all types implementing `std::error::Error`](https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.5/failure/trait.Fail.html#impl-Fail-3) (as long as they are also `Send + Sync + 'static`). In combination, this allows us to return any type implementing either the `failure::Fail` trait or the `std::error::Error` trait. All error types in the standard library implement the `Error` trait, including `std::io::Error` and `std::num::ParseIntError`.

This already explains why the code compiles, but it does not explain how the conversions work internally. This is explained by the second mechanism at play – trait objects. The (slightly redacted) definition of the `Error` type in the `failure` crate is this:

```
struct Error {
    imp: ErrorImpl,
}

struct ErrorImpl {
    inner: Box<Inner<dyn Fail>>,
}

struct Inner<F: ?Sized + Fail> {
    backtrace: Backtrace,
    failure: F,
}
```

The `Inner` type stores the error as a trait object that uses dynamic dispatch for method calls.

Answer (score 1):

The `failure::Error::from_boxed_compat` constructor is used to convert any error to a `failure::Error`.

```rust
pub fn from_boxed_compat(err: Box<dyn StdError + Sync + Send + 'static>) -> Error
```

This funciton takes any struct that impl Error as input and constructs a `failure::Error`
https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.5/failure/struct.Error.html#impl

`failure::Error` contains a heap stored trait object inside it that can store a struct that implements the Error object.

```rust
struct ErrorImpl {
    inner: Box<Inner<Fail>>,
}
```

Additionally, it looks like the `Fail trait` is implemented for many errors. The `?` operator will add an `into` method that will convert an Error to a `failure::Error`

Comment: How is `from_boxed_compat()` relevant here? It is true that it can take a boxed `std::error::Error` and convert it to `failure::Error`, but there are no boxed errors in the OP's code, nor any call to that function.